# Freedom of movement directive after a hard Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, freedom-of-movement

Would the freedom of movement directive automatically cease to apply to the UK after a hard Brexit or is some sort of parliamentary action necessary for that?

Answer (score 4):

The current law is that it would cease to apply at 11 PM GMT on March 29th 2019. The plan was to pass further legislation that transposed all EU rules, including freedom of movement, into British law before then, but in the event of a no-deal crash that probably wouldn't happen.

However, the British government has indicated that it would want to keep some aspects of freedom of movement, particularly good goods, and to an extent for services, capital and people. The extent of this is unclear at this time, but for example it does not wish to see any border infrastructure in Ireland and people who cross the border for work may be able to continue to do so. This would all require parliamentary action to implement.

Comment: I'd like a citation on the plan to transpose freedom of movement into UK law. I feel reasonably certain every flavour of Brexiteer is opposed to freedom of movement after Brexit (At least of people). https://www.personneltoday.com/hr/government-confirms-end-to-freedom-of-movement-with-potential-exceptions/

Comment: @Jontia Boris Johnson, according to [the Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-freedom-movement-can-continue-says-boris-johnson-a7672741.html). After the meaningful vote I also heard him say he wanted a Canada-style trade deal which would allow an open border between the UK and Ireland so I assume that would also imply FoM of people.

Comment: The first paragraph isn't quite right. The EU (Withdrawal) Act 2018 already retains all EU law in British law after exit day - but gives the Government the right to make any changes after that date that they deem necessary. So for this directive, it will remain law unless and until the Government change it.

Comment: @JJJ the UK can let in whoever it likes in wants on whatever terms it wants.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff my understanding was that it wasn't automatic. Much of the law in question assumes EU membership and names EU institutions that the UK will no longer be part of. Therefore it needs to be fixed, which was the purpose of the "Henry VIII clauses", to allow ministers to do that without the usual oversight and scrutiny.

Comment: @user nevertheless, the Brexit campaign said they needed brexit to put in controls on immigration and the electorate bought it.

Comment: Keeping some but not all of the free market rules is something the EU has explicitly said is not an option for the UK. As the UK would need unanimous consent to enact something like that (not unlike a trade deal) in the case of a no deal brexit, it would cease to apply and would need to be first re-negotiated and then passed into law. While yes, the UK can let in whoever it wants, the EU is also free in that aspect, and is probably not going to extend the benefits of the free market to the UK without further consideration.

Comment: @user: the fixing has already started. For example, [here's a statutory instrument (SI) published yesterday](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2019/96/made). As you can see, a lot of it concerned with replacing references to EU bodies with references to UK equivalents. Many SIs like this have already been made, and more are on their way.

Comment: @Magisch oh sure, UK citizens and goods couldn't enjoy Freedom of Movement, but the UK can keep it going for EU citizens.

Comment: For freedom of movement of people to end in the UK, the Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016 have to be repealed, which cannot take effect before the UK leaves the EU, whenever that is.  The directive losing its effect in the UK does not by itself end freedom of movement for EU citizens in the UK. In other words, @SteveMelnikoff is correct.  Because directives do not have direct effect, but must be transposed into national law, it is necessary to repeal the national legislation to change the status of EU citizens and their family members in the UK.

Comment: @phoog, thank you for the clarification, would you like to formulate that as an answer?